# HTML code as text in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, escaping, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have an Excel file that will be saved as an .csv file for importation into an email automation system. In a function I need to return a piece of HTML code as text.

```
=IF(A2<0,"CHECKMARK CODE",A2)
```

The "CHECKMARK CODE" needs to be replaced by:

```
>    < span style="font-size:16px">& #10003;</span>.
```

For this post, spaces were added to prevent code from display as a checkmark.

However, all my attempts at the `format_text` function or adding apostrophes only yields errors.

How do I return this as text exactly as needed by the email automation system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try escaping the double quotes:

```
=IF(A2<0,"<span style=""font-size:16px"">& #10003;</span>",A2)
```